# Highcharts: Stacked area drilldown to multiple series

Tags: javascript, python, html, highcharts

I am trying to present a graph that shows the current progress with an ongoing project. So basically once you open the plot, it will show you a plot of Passed, Failed and not run test runs in a stacked area.

I want to drilldown on the main data (Passed, Failed, Not Run). I want to basically show the teams(s) that may have passed, failed, or not run. Let's say that you want to drill down on "Passed", once you click on "Passed", it should bring multiple series, each serie containing the team name and the amount of Passed tests.

```
JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9aqbLzar/3/
```

Demo:

```js
Highcharts.Tick.prototype.drillable = function() {};
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    drillUpText: '◁ Go back'
  }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    title: {
      text: "Test runs"
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      lineColor: null,
      lineWidth: 1,
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: null,
        symbol: 'circle',
        radius: 3
      }
    },
    cursor: 'pointer',
    trackByArea: true
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Passed',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 06),
        y: 20,
        drilldown: 'Passed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 07),
        y: 21,
        drilldown: 'Passed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 08),
        y: 22,
        drilldown: 'Passed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
        y: 23,
        drilldown: 'Passed'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Failed',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 06),
        y: 6,
        drilldown: 'Failed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 07),
        y: 5,
        drilldown: 'Failed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 08),
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'Failed'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
        y: 3,
        drilldown: 'Failed'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Not run',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 06),
        y: 8,
        drilldown: 'Not run'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 07),
        y: 7,
        drilldown: 'Not run'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 08),
        y: 6,
        drilldown: 'Not run'
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
        y: 5,
        drilldown: 'Not run'
      }]
    }
  ],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: 'Passed',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 12),
        y: 2
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 13),
        y: 3
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 14),
        y: 5
      }]
    }, {
      id: 'Failed',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 10),
        y: 6
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
        y: 7
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 12),
        y: 8
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 13),
        y: 9
      }]
    }, {
      id: 'Not run',
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 10),
        y: 6
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
        y: 7
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 12),
        y: 8
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 13),
        y: 9
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I've included your code within the code snippet option stack overflow offers. It will be easier for the other users to include it in their answer and avoid links to external sites like `jsfiddle.net`.

Comment: @tgogos - It is fine to use the code snippet option stack overflow offers, but it is many times easier to manipulate and play with a `jsfiddle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to have multiple drilldown series for each series (e.g. three for the 'Passed', three for the 'Failed', three for the 'Not run'). Secondly, the only way to drilldown to more than one series is to add them on `drilldown` event with a function called `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown`. When desired series are added all you need to do is to apply them with `applyDrilldown` function. Take a look at the example below and in case of any question, feel free to ask.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7a6gh7vz/

Comment: You sir, are awesome!